# angularjs and template table

Tags: angularjs, html-table

I would like to build an html table based on a model.

I want to do something like that:

```
Student         | competence 1                        |
                | subject 1                | subject 2|
                | exam 1 | exam2 | average |          |
xxxxx yyyyyyyyy |   10   | 20    |   15    | 45       |
```

And here is how I'm trying to do this:

```
table(ng-controller="ExaminationListCtrl")
  tr
    th(ng-repeat="(competence, s) in competenceToSubjectSize", colspan="{{s.length}}")
      {{competence}}
  tr
    th(ng-repeat="subject in subjects")
      {{subject.subject}}
```

My issue is that I can't use `colspan="{{s.length}}"`, it seems to me that `"competence"` and `s` are only bound to the child of th elements
How could I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was wrong since the top tag we could access to the scope marked with the ng-repeat